versel deploment error while uploading the project
⨯ useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/auth-callback". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { trpc } from "../_trpc/client";
import { Loader2 } from "lucide-react";

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const origin = searchParams.get("origin");

  const { data, error, isLoading } = trpc.authCallback.useQuery(undefined, {
    retry: true,
    retryDelay: 500,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error && error.data?.code === "UNAUTHORIZED") {
      router.push("/sign-in");
    } else if (!isLoading && !error) {
      router.push(origin ? `/${origin}` : "/dashboard");
    }
  }, [isLoading, error, origin, router]);

  return (
    <div className="w-full mt-24 flex justify-center">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-2">
        <Loader2 className="h-8 w-8 animate-spin text-zinc-800" />
        <h3 className="font-semibold text-xl">
          Setting up your account...
        </h3>
        <p>You will be redirected automatically.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;


The link you have posted describes your error and how to fix it. You must wrap any call to useSearchParams in a Suspense boundary.
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import { Suspense } from 'react'
 
function Search() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  return <input placeholder="Search..." />
}
 
export function Searchbar() {
  return (
    // You could have a loading skeleton as the `fallback` too
    <Suspense>
      <Search />
    </Suspense>
  )
}

Make a component which calls SearchParams and a a suspense boundary around it, which you have not done in your code example.
